# Возможно ли инвертировать порядок бит в байте?

Tags: битовые-операции, c, c++

Т.е. можно ли средствами C++ из 1100 0000 превратить в 0000 0011 ? Какие для этого нужно использовать методы?

Comment: Ок, задача такая: есть x1: 0001 1101  
                      x2: 1110 0011. Мне нужно из этой последовательности получить 1110 1110 ... . Для этого я составил следующую формулу: x1 xor (x2 & F0). Но (x2 & F0) выдает 1100 000, а надо 0000 0011.

Comment: @MartinSeptim, странная задача, представьте ваше число как строку и разверните её.

Comment: Эмммм... asm bswap не модно уже?

Comment: @ToRcH565, увы ассемблера я не знаю.

Comment: @ToRcH565, `bswap` делает другое - она переставляет байты

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Как известно, байт - это восьмиразрядное двоичное число. Стало быть, его можно представить в виде такого многочлена:

```
b1 * 2^7 + b2 * 2^6 + ...  + b7 * 2^1 + b8 * 2^0
```

ну или

```
128 * b1 + 64 * b2 + ...  + 2 *  b7 + 1 * b8
```

где b1 - b8 - биты в байте. 
Следовательно, получить байт "задом наперёд" можно так:

```
unsigned char Invert(unsigned char x) 
{        
    int base = 256;

    unsigned char  res = 0;
    while (x != 0) 
    {
        res += (x & 1) * (base >>= 1);
        x >>= 1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Вот средство языка (циклы и битовые операции)

```
int main() {
  int a,b;
  a = 0xC0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    b = b<<1;
    b += a%2;
    a = a>>1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Или чуть более в духе таких штучек в Си


    b = 0
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      b <<= 1;
      b |= (a & 1);
      a >>= 1;
    }
    a = b;

Answer (score 5):

```
template<typename T>
const T reversebits(const T& in)
{
    T out = T(0);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T) * 8; ++i)
    {
        out <<= 1;
        out |= (in >> i)&1;
    }

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Бит-реверсивная перестановка используется в алгоритме FFT (быстрое дискретное преобразование Фурье) для `2^n` точек.

Простейший способ реализации - табличный (256 байтов).

Но можно применить и стратегию дублирования, при которой на первом шаге попарно переставляются соседние тетрады, на втором - диады и на третьем - биты:
abcdefgh - efghabcd - ghefcdab - hgfedcba.

Возможна такая реализация (на месте), допускающая использование макросов:
b = ((b >> 4) & 15) | ((b & 15) << 4);
b = ((b >> 2) & 51) | ((b & 51) << 2);
b = ((b >> 1) & 85) | ((b & 85) << 1);
Имеется в виду, что 15=0b00001111, 51=0b00110011, 85=0b01010101.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define INVERT_BYTE(a)   ((a&1)<<7) | ((a&2)<<5) | ((a&4)<<3) | ((a&8)<<1) | ((a&16)>>1) | ((a&32)>>3) | ((a&64)>>5) | ((a&128)>>7)
```